# Can I output only the first instance of a value from a datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Is it possible to output only the first instance of a value stored in a data table?

My example is this = I have a datatable wherein each row contains the name of a month. The table is ordered by month, in ascending order. I want to output the name of the month only on its first occurence in the table - if there are five entries with the month January, the text 'January' only needs be output once.

I'm using a repeater - code below. The value in Month should only change if it is different to the value in the previous row.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEvents" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <h5><%#Eval("Month")%></h5>     
        <p>
            <strong><asp:HyperLink ID="hlEvents" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>' NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("QuickLink") %>'></asp:HyperLink></strong><br />
    <%#Eval("Date") %><br />
    <%#Eval("Description") %>
    </p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: can't you distinct while selecting from database? Or even when giving datasource to that repeater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Well, I'm not sure but how about doing it on the db-side?

    SELECT MIN(DISTNCT Month), Title, QuickLink FROM Title, QuickLink</del>


UPDATE:
Seems like I was misunderstood. How about using a method?

```
<h5><%#GetMonthName(Eval("Month"))%></h5>
```

And in code-behind, define a class-scope variable to hold the previous month name and compare it to the current month name in your method:

```
// this is a private class-scope variable.
private static string prevMonthName = string.Empty;

public string GetMonth(string curMonthName)
{
  if (curMonthName == prevMonthName)
  {
    return string.Empty;
  }
  prevMonthName = curMonthName;
  return curMonthName;
}
```

Comment: I've pretty much used your solution - rather than using a method in the control, i've called GetMonth directly when I'm populating the datatable. Works a treat.

Comment: @Nathan: Glad to hear it could help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to have 2 Repeaters. The outer will bind to month list and the inner all entries within the month:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MonthList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="MonthList_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h2><%# Container.DataItem %></h2>
        <asp:Repeater ID="ItemList" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Name") %></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

For this markup code behind may look like:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class Entry
    {
        public string Month {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
    }

    List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>()
    {
        new Entry() { Month = "Jan", Name = "name1"},
        new Entry() { Month = "Jan", Name = "name2"},
        new Entry() { Month = "Feb", Name = "name3"},
        new Entry() { Month = "Aug", Name = "name4"},
        new Entry() { Month = "Dec", Name = "name5"},
        new Entry() { Month = "Dec", Name = "name6"}
    };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            MonthList.DataSource = entries.GroupBy(x => x.Month).Select(x => x.Key);
            MonthList.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void MonthList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            var itemList = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("ItemList");
            var month = (string)e.Item.DataItem;
            itemList.DataSource = entries.Where(x => x.Month == month);
            itemList.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

I used in-memory collection for the sample and Linq to convert it. First, we group the data source by Month. Then, in MonthList_ItemDataBound, for each month being bound we look for the inner repeater and bind it with a collection filtered by current (DataItem) month. Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated my answer with a sample.